# Jetpack Compose Build Issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I keep getting this error while trying to build the project. I have tried all of the other solutions which I found on stackoverflow regarding similar issue with Jetpack compose. Have anyone been able to build succussfully as of Jan 10, 2022. Thank You!

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.

> Could not find androidx.compose:compose-compiler:1.0.5.
> Searched in the following locations:

````
       buildFeatures {
        compose = true
       }

    
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.4.21-2"
//      kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.0-alpha11"
//      kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.1.0-rc02"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.5"
    }     
        
        


        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.1.0-rc01"
        implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.5"
        // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
        implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.5"
        // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
        implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.5"
        // Material Design
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.5"
        // Material design icons
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.5" 
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.5"
        // Integration with observables
        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.5"
        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.0.5" ```
````

Comment: Why are you mixing 1.1.0 and 1.0.5 ?

Comment: compose 1.0.5 requires kotlin version 1.5.31, and you seems using 1.4.21-2 for some reason. Also all dependencies under `androidx.compose....` should be of the same version - for example 1.0.5, and you have `runtime:1.1.0-rc01`

Comment: You need Kotlin 1.5.31